# How to allow uploading of photos while placing an order using Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to WordPress, and want to use Woocommerce for my online shop. However, I am creating things using photos supplied by the customer for certain products. Other products can be sold as is.

That means if the customer orders an item in this category, he needs to upload the photo to be used to create that item while placing his order. This photo must be linked to the order, and must not be visible to the other customers, but only to me when I view his order.

Is there any existing WordPress theme that caters for this, and if not, how do I modify Woocommerce to cater for this?

More than one customer can order the same product, and each customer must be able to upload his photo to be used for that product for that order. Each client's photo must *only* be linked to that specific order for that specific customer for that specific date.

Comment: Something like [Personalized Product Options](http://www.najeebmedia.com/n-media-woocommerce-personalized-product-options-manager/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Woothemes's [Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) plugin. It allows you to add custom fields to your product including file-inputs. These fields will be displayed on the front-end & user can fill their values/upload files which will be included with their orders. And as an admin, only you will be able to see the values/files in the order-details section.

Answer (score 0):

You required to add image with each product, which should not be display to your customer, only to you while some order placed by customer: 
In this case you required to add custom field over there in Product Custom Post type. 
**You can refer to this link for creating Custom Field** 
http://wp-types.com/learn/create-an-ecommerce-wordpress-site/create-custom-fields-and-taxonomies/

Comment: Hi,I'm sorry. You misunderstand. I do not want to add an image to the product, each customer ordering that product needs to send me their photo that I will use to create that product for them. If 10 customers order that product, those 10 customers each need to upload their photos to their orders in order for me to create the end product for them. The photos need to be uploaded in the order, and not on the product itself. Thank you for your time.